# difference between globalization and localization, where to use , when to use, same as what is culture and cultureUI

Tags: c#, wpf

anyone can you give me the perfect word for this difference between globalization and localization, where to use , when to use, same as what is culture and cultureUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you localize a WPF application, you have several options. For example, you can bind the localizable resources in your application to an XML file, store localizable text in resx tables, or have your localizer use Extensible Application Markup Language (XAML) files, which provides several benefits:

-You can localize after you build .

-You can update to a newer version of the BAML form of XAMLwith localizations  from an older version of the BAML form of XAML so that you can localize at the  same time that you develop.

-You can validate original source elements and semantics at compile time because the BAML form of XAML is the compiled form of XAML.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is a link-only answer. 
Please try to summarize the content of the page you've linked in case the resource goes offline.